# recording audio call using Skype?

Tags: skype

I need to make a web application that would be able to call a ground phone ( obviously through Skype ) and record the conversation... any ideas, where do I start? ( yes, already tried google :) ) can it be done in php?

Thanks!

Comment: @Zaid depends on your jurisdiction, but quite likely no.

Comment: legal and moral issues would be the user's responsibility.

Comment: as long as you record the voice agreeing on that the `conversation is been recorded`, nothing will harm user and recorded person

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like there are a lot of things you haven't thought of yet, but to answer your actual question, you could do part of it in PHP, and start by googling the following:

- skype api
- recording sound with flash
- legality of recording telephone calls by country and state

... and by thinking about what neferious uses people might put your application to...

Comment: thanks, i'll google into that. as for legality, the user would have to confirm that what he is doing is legal in his country/state. nefarious uses... such as? :)

Comment: You'd want to check your legal position at least in your own jurisdiction first, since you may find yourself responsible for calls placed though your system.  As for neferious uses... well, it's a free anonymous way of making phone calls - you could find people making junk calls, harrassing people, or even more serious crimes.  You might also find your Skype account banned from making outgoing calls pretty quickly too.